# Show that permutations of $n$ have no increasing or decreasing sequences longer than ⌈$\sqrt n$⌉ for any $n$.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

While doing Pigeonhole principle in our class, our professor mentioned and proved that every permutation of $n$ either has a decreasing or an increasing subsequence of length ⌈$\sqrt n$⌉.

But how do I prove that the above theorem is the strongest possible ?

Comment: Maybe $2 0 3 1$ for $n = 4$

Comment: I mean, i want to prove that this is the strongest possible result. I don't want examples.

Comment: A single counter example is enough to show that no stronger theorem exists. In this example, no increasing or decreasing sequence of length 3 i.e. greater than $\sqrt 4$

Comment: This is the [Erdős–Szekeres_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős–Szekeres_theorem)

Comment: You might be interested in this YouTube video: [Order From Chaos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwIAfkuXc5A)

Comment: @HelloWorld1729 I was going to answer your question, until you posted your comment. You need to understand that a counterexample is exactly what you are looking for. In order to prove that the result your professor mentioned is a strong as possible, you just need to show there exists a single permutation of length $n$ without any monotone subsequences of length $\lceil \sqrt n\rceil +1$. Such a spoiler would show it is impossible to guarantee a monotone subsequence of length $\lceil \sqrt n \rceil +1$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I understand what you wrote. but I want to find permutations for "any" $n$. Is there a closed form of such permutations ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof that $\lceil \sqrt n\rceil$ is the best result possible, for all $n$.

Given $n$, let $s=\lceil \sqrt n\rceil$. Note that $s^2$ is the smallest perfect square which is greater than or equal to $n$. Every integer in the range $\{0,1,\dots,s^2-1\}$ can be uniquely written in the form
$$
i\cdot s+j,\qquad i,j\in \{0,1,\dots,s-1\}
$$
First, we will define a permutation $\pi$ of length $s^2$ without any monotone sequences of length $s+1$. Then, we will modify $\pi$ so it has length $n$, but still without any monotone sequences of length $s+1$.

$$
\begin{align}
\pi:\{0,1,\dots,s^2-1\}&\to \{0,1,\dots,s^2-1\}\\
i\cdot s+j&\mapsto j\cdot s + (s-1-i) 
\end{align}
$$
When $s=4$, this looks like
$$
\pi=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15\\
3&7&11&15&2&6&10&14&1&5&9&13&0&4&8&12\end{matrix}\right)
$$
This takes care of the cases when $n=s^2$ is a perfect square. Otherwise, we need to shorten $\pi$. We do this by only keeping the first $n$ entries of $\pi$. Then, we reduce these entries so that they are in the range $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ without changing their relative ordering.

For example, suppose $n=11$. We find $s=4$, so we start with the above $\pi$. We then only keep the first $11$ entries, resulting in
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
3&7&11&15&2&6&10&14&1&5&9
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
The domain is now $\{0,1,\dots,10\}$, which is correct, but the range is all wrong. To fix this, replace the smallest number in the range with $0$, the second smallest number in the range with $1$, and so on. The resulting permutation of length $11$ with no monotone subsequences of length $5$ is
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
2&5&8&10&1&4&7&9&0&3&6
\end{matrix}\right)
$$